# New SharePoint 2019 Instance Site Template

Tags: site-template, 2019

We are spinning up a new 2019 SharePoint on prem instance with the intention of migrating our 2013 data to it. Our 2013 main stie has a site template of SPS#0 (SharePoint Portal Server) which is now obsolete. All of our subsites were created using STS#0 (Team Sites).  Any recommendations for our 2019 main site template?  We'll be creating all the new subsites with the Team Sites template, should we just use that?

Answer (score 1):

Primary portal I would suggest a Communication template while you use STS#3 for Team sites.